# PHP CSV compare columns

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I created a CSV as follows:

```
Name,Title,Salary,Bonus
Bob White,Manager,50000,1000
Mia Sparrow,Programmer,60000,1500
Steven Seagull,Programmer,58000,1400
```

and then the code below as suggested:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$data = [];
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data[] = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
print_r($data);
?>
```

but instead of this output:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name
        [1] => Title
        [2] => Salary
        [3] => Bonus
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bob White
        [1] => Manager
        [2] => 50000
        [3] => 1000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Mia Sparrow
        [1] => Programmer
        [2] => 60000
        [3] => 1500
    )
```

I'm getting all in one line:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ��NAME    TITLE   SALARY  BONUS ) [1] => Array ( [0] => BOB   MANAGER 50000   1000 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => MIA    PROGRAMMER  600001  1500 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => STEVEN PROGRAMMER 58000    1400 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => ) [5] => )
```

How can I split this into arrays by key so that I can use :

```
print_r(array_column($data,X));
```

to print the column I need?

Comment: show the fragment of `test.csv` contents

Comment: Could just do `echo $data[$salaryColumnIndex]+$data[$bonusColumnIndex]` if you know those indices.

Comment: If I do echo $data[1] perhaps, it gives me error: Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 0):

As you're looping over the array, simply sum whatever columns correspond to `salary` and `bonus`, then output the total at the end.

If you change this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
```

to:

```
$data = [];
while (($data[] = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
```

you'll end up with the entire contents of the file in $data, and then you can perform various [array operations](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) on it.

[EDIT]

Ok, this is what I'm talking about in the first part. Let's say your .csv file looks something like this:

```
Name,Title,Salary,Bonus
Bob White,Manager,50000,1000
Mia Sparrow,Programmer,60000,1500
Steven Seagull,Programmer,58000,1400
```

Now, this will give you a sum of the bonus and salary columns, and add them together for a total:

```
const SALARY = 2;
const BONUS  = 3;

$salary = 0;
$bonus  = 0;

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $salary+= $data[SALARY];
      $bonus+=  $data[BONUS];
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "Totals: ".$salary."+".$bonus." = ".($salary + $bonus);
}
```

If you want to do some other operations on your data, you can store the whole thing in an array, like this:

```
$row = 1;
$data = [];
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data[] = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Now, `print_r($data);` will give you this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name
            [1] => Title
            [2] => Salary
            [3] => Bonus
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bob White
            [1] => Manager
            [2] => 50000
            [3] => 1000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mia Sparrow
            [1] => Programmer
            [2] => 60000
            [3] => 1500
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Steven Seagull
            [1] => Programmer
            [2] => 58000
            [3] => 1250
        )

    [4] => 
)
```

and `print_r(array_column($data,2));` will give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Salary
    [1] => 50000
    [2] => 60000
    [3] => 58000
)
```

Does that help?

Comment: I tried your code above but it gives me an error: ( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\code.php on line 10
Thank you